# which of the two mean that the person is not worthy enough that a biopic should be made on his life?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> "I don't think I'm worthy enough to have a biopic **being**  made on me" *or*
>   "I don't think I'm worthy enough to have a biopic made on me"

I always have trouble with such construction, but am yet to conclude what it is that troubles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A narrative is "about" its subject/topic, not "on" it.

*Enough* is redundant in this context.

*Worthy* is pretty much confined to non-colloquial registers these days, so I wouldn't pair it with the breezy journalism *biopic*.

And the standard construction is *worthy **of** X*, where X is a noun phrase or gerund-participle clause:

> I am not worthy of having a film biography made about me.

If you want something a little more colloquial I'd say something like

> I'm not important enough to make a movie about.

Comment: what do you think is the best way I (or anyone) can improve upon my sentence construction. Will  just reading ease out my way.

Comment: @MUMBAS That's really a question that belongs on [languagelearning.se]. But as a general rule I'd say the more you read, the more familiar you will become with the syntax of English, or any other language.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the same thing, but it makes more sense to be talking about a *finished* product.

Therefore:

> ✔ have a biopic made
>   ✘ have a biopic ***being*** made

When you use *being* here, you are talking about something that is still happening.